# PyCharm error message regarding "console process"

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I'm still getting used to the multiple pieces coming together around Python (Anaconda and PyCharm in particular).

I get this message (pasted below) after a long wait for PyCharm to deploy, and wonder if it can have an easy fix, and what its meaning is.

```
  C:\Anaconda2\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 2320 2321
    Couldn't connect to console process.
    Process finished with exit code -1
```